# Better way to write 'assign A or if not possible - B'

Tags: python, compound-assignment

So, in my code I have a dictionary I use to count up items I have no prior knowledge of:

```
if a_thing not in my_dict:
    my_dict[a_thing] = 0
else:
    my_dict[a_thing] += 1
```

Obviously, I can't increment an entry of a value that doesn't exist yet. For some reason I have a feeling (in my still-Python-inexperienced brain) there might exist a more Pythonic way to do this with, say, some construct which allows to assign a result of an expression to a thing and if not possible something else **in a single statement**.

So, does anything like that exist in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a good job for [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), from `collections`. Observe the example below:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d['a'] += 1
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 1})
>>> d['b'] += 1
>>> d['a'] += 1
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'b': 1, 'a': 2})
```

`defaultdict` will take a single parameter which indicates your initial value. In this case you are incrementing integer values, so you want `int`.

Alternatively, since you are counting items, you could also (as mentioned in comments) use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which will ultimately do all the work for you:

```
>>> d = Counter(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> d
Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 2})
```

It also comes with some nice bonuses. Like `most_common`:

```
>>> d.most_common()
[('a', 3), ('c', 2), ('b', 2)]
```

Now you have an order to give you the most common counts.

Comment: Note that `defaultdict(int)` is basically `collections.Counter()`

Comment: @vaultah Yeah. Thanks. That *should* have been the first solution I thought of. I added it.

Answer (score 1):

using `get` method

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['a'] = d.get('a', 0) + 1
>>> d
{'a': 1}
>>> d['b'] = d.get('b', 2) + 1
>>> d
{'b': 3, 'a': 1}
```